# How can I use a dark theme for all webpages on Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, dark-mode

How can I use a dark theme for all webpages on Chrome for Android?

I don't mean having a dark theme for only the Google chrome UI (which can be done via Settings, Theme, Dark Mode) but also the webpages themselves, so this can be done with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/morpheon-dark/mafbdhjdkjnoafhfelkjpchpaepjknad?hl=en on Google Chrome for desktop.

Example of website with no dark theme:

[image]

Comment: This is usually done with CSS injection, which [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207352) asks (but not yet answered...)

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

- Open Chrome
- Tap the 3 dots in the top right corner
- Tap Settings
- Tap Themes
- Select Dark

I haven't come across a site that this doesn't work on yet

Comment: Thanks, doing so changed the Chrome UI to dark theme, but not the webpages themselves, from what I can see.

Comment: Strange. Which version of Chrome are you using? Mine is 79.0.3945.136

Comment: I use the same version. Example of website with no dark theme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQBud.jpg do you have a dark theme?